Recomendaciones para certificar SQL
Hola quiero estudiar un curso para certificarme en SQl, ¿Cuál me podrían recomendar, que sea completo y certificado bueno?

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

La única certificación de Microsoft SQL Server disponible es DP-300 (Microsoft Certified Database Administrator) y también incluye Azure SQL. Aquí puedes encontrar entrenamiento/cursos gratuitos y puedes encontrar entrenamiento pagado.
Es el examen más difícil que he tomado de certificación.

Genial, voy a revisarlo muchas gracias

Siempre a la orden. Cualquier ayuda a la orden.
